# Keyboard intermittently stops working on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, ubuntu-12.04

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS on my desktop and my keyboard will occasionally stop responding for a few seconds. It immediately begins about a second or so afterwards, so nothing freezes. Just now I was typing 'immediately' and it typed 'immed' so I paused and typed again and I was able to finish the word!

I run into the same problem when I SSH into the machine, so I know it is not a hardware problem. I originally found the problem when I was SSHing in, so I always thought it was a latency/lag issue, but am now experiencing it when am locally at the machine.

Any ideas what can be causing this or how to fix it?